# outdent with Shift+Tab in eclipse / Zend Studio

Tags: eclipse, tabs, space, zend-studio, shortcut

I'm using Zend Studio 9 and have a trouble with outdent (Shift+Tab). It works only if left of the begin of the line is a tab:

```
[tab]return array();
```

but doesn't work for the spaces:

```
[space][space][space][space]return array();
```

Does someone have a solution for ZS 9 for this problem?

Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [change Zend Studio tab policy to spaces](http://www.phpepe.com/2013/12/zend-studio-insert-spaces-for-tabs.html)

Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Code Style -> Formatter

[image]

[image]

Comment: Posting link-only answers is generally discouraged, because the link may become invalid in future. Could you please edit your post to explain the solution in your own words? It is ok to include the link as part of a more verbose answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a selection on the line, and then it should work. It also works if the selection is on more than one line.

Comment: It works -- both for one and for multiple lines. But only with tabs. It doesn't work with lines, which have spaces (instead of tabs) at the begin.